# How to Cut One Shape at the Stroke of Another in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This would be quite simple but I can't see to do it.

I have a shape/object (shape 1) and another shape object (shape 2).

Shape one has fill and a stroke (1px black). Shape 2 has a fill but no stroke.

Shape 1 is bigger than shape 2 and shape 2 sits on top of shape 1 in such as way that some part of shape 2 is on shape 1 and the rest part of shape 2 is outside shape 1.

How would I go about "cutting" the shape 2 and delete that part of the shape 2 that is outside shape 1 and leave me only the part of shape 2 that is inside the shape 1 in such a way that the stoke of shape 1 is visible.

[image: Photo]

Comment: I tried pathfinder, but it does not work

Comment: What exactly did you do with Pathfinder? That's the tool you need.

Comment: @Lauren lpsum : Tried all the functions. Add, Unite, Delete. I think there are 6. But in some cases i get the desired results but the stroke also gets deleted. This is a simplifaction of my problem. In actual both shapes are irregularl. i.e., they are not rectangle or circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly.....

1. Select both shapes
2. copy
3. Delete shape 2
4. Select Shape 1 and Object > Hide (this is just to make it easier and is not required)
5. Edit > paste in front
6. Select Shape 1
7. Object > Expand
8. Pathfinder > Minus Front
9. Select Both Shape 1 and Shape 2
10. Pathfinder > Minus Back
11. Object > Show All (To unhide Shape 1 in step 4)

Result : lower half of Shape 2 by itself trimmed to match edge of Shape 1.

What this does is expands Shape 1 then trims the size of the stroke from the shape allowing the Minus Back to only use the inner area of Shape 1.

Answer (score 3):

You have a fundamental issue with how you conceive your shapes.  You want to "cut" Shape 2 using Shape 1, yet you want the resulting shape to include space for Shape 1's stroke.  There isn't a simple way to do that - any method you try will require you to take Shape 1's stroke into account.

There are several ways to do this, but I would do the following:

1. Copy Shape 1 and paste in back (if you want to keep it).
2. Select Shape 1 and perform `Object` ⇒ `Expand` (check both Fill and Stroke)
3. Ungroup Shape 1's expanded components.
4. With Shape 1's components selected, use `Subtract from shape area` on the Pathfinder menu.  (This will give you a fill object that is smaller than your original Shape 1)
5. Select Shape 2 and your new, smaller fill object from Shape 1 and select `Intersect shape areas` on the Pathfinder menu.

This will give you an object that is constrained by the visible fill area of your Shape 1 object.